# how to set a android view pager unclickable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-viewpager

i am developing a application with android view pager i want to set view pager in not click able state.
i try all

```
            myviewpager.setFocusable(false);
            myviewpager.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            myviewpager.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);
            myviewpager.setLongClickable(false);
            myviewpager.setClickable(false);
            myviewpager.setPressed(false);
            myviewpager.setSelected(false);
            myviewpager.setEnabled(false);
```

but not working on view pager anyone knows how to set a view pager clickable disable state
plz help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code in your custom `ViewPager` implementation. This will enable you to disable the viewpager as expected.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
```

Comment: I want to do the same thing. For the swiping I followed this "http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/" 
and it works
But this code you provided cannot be added to a class that extends PagerAdapter, but into a class that extends ViewPager
So how could I use "onTouchEvent" and "onInterceptTouchEvent" on my  myPagerAdapter class? 
This may be some silly question but I'm confused, please help!

Comment: The link is this 
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/

Comment: Where do you even put this?